# How does the TCP/IP lack security?

Tags: encryption, tcp

I already know that some concerns of lack of security in TCP/IP are that TCP/IP does not support strong authentication of packets and no encryption of packets. What other weaknesses are there in the TCP/IP regarding security concerns?

Comment: Some "weaknesses" I know regarding TCP/IP (not in TCP/IT itself, but rather in the implementations): TCP syn flooding, TCP window attack (with size set to zero in the ack packet), sequence number guessing, IP spoofing. These weaknesses are not present in IPv6. Read more here: http://cs.ucsb.edu/~koc/ns/projects/00Reports/LV.pdf

Answer (score 5):

## Routing is a black box

You generally have no way to tell how your communication is routed through the internet. You never know which routers pass on your communication and who controls them. Routers can be configured to divert certain traffic to go across non-trustworthy servers and the endpoints have really no way to detect this. You might know about the `traceroute` (UNIX) or `tracert` (Windows) program which discovers the route between you and another host, but the network traffic generated by this tool looks and behaves a lot different than normal traffic, which makes this tool quite unreliable. Normal traffic might take an entirely different route than what traceroute shows you.

## Address spoofing

Each IP packet includes both the IP address it is sent to as well as the address it orginates from. However, there is by default no verification that the source address is really the address of the host which created the message. This allows any host to forge an IP packet with the source IP of any other host and claiming it is routing it from it. This problem is much more serious for UDP/IP than TCP/IP, because TCP/IP requires a SYN/ACK/SYN-ACK handshake to establish a connection, which only works when the source-IP of the packet which makes the connection is correct. However, there is also...

## Sequence number guessing

When two hosts have established a connection, each packet they exchange is numbered. When an attacker knows that two hosts are communicating with each other and they can guess the next sequence-number, they can spoof such a packet to inject forged data into the communication.

And another application of address spoofing is:

## SYN-Flooding

This is a denial-of-service attack where the attacking host sends lots of SYN-packets (requests to open a connection) to the target host. However, it spoofs the source-IP with random addresses, so the server sends an ACK-packet (acceptance of the connection) to a host which never asked for it. It will then wait for the SYN-ACK packet (acknowledgment of acceptance by the initiator) until timeout. This can bind a large amount of resources on the host and prevent it from accepting legitimate connections. While this does not result in any data exposure or data manipulation, it is still a frequently used method to temporarily prevent users from reaching a certain host.

But what if you actually need to read the response of a host to a spoofed packet? Well, then you have:

## ARP spoofing

Strictly speaking, this is not a flaw in TCP/IP but in the related Address Resolution Protocol which binds IP addresses to network interfaces. However, it affects the security of IP communication, because it allows one host to "steal" the IP address of another host so that any future IP packets get redirected. ARP spoofing usually only works in the same network segment. Also, an ARP poisioning attack can be detected and enterprise-grade network equipment is usually able to prevent it.

**By the way:** Needless to say, using any of the methods described here are illegal in many parts of the world. Nevertheless they are frequently used by criminals and government institutions all around the world.

Answer (score 3):

TCP/IP is strong against environmental hazards, not against malicious intelligent attackers. TCP/IP was designed, from start, with security in mind, but in a quite specific context: resilience against nuclear war. The initial goal of TCP/IP was to allow critical US military infrastructure to keep communication goings while under bombardment from communist warheads. As such, TCP/IP *assumes* that, at the logical level, the various connected hosts are cooperating; the problem is really to resist loss of a considerable fraction of the said hosts.

It turned out that some of the nuclear-resistance features of TCP/IP can be a hindrance to modern *electronic* attackers -- e.g. the redundant routing can work around local intentional disruption, and the TCP sequence numbers (initially meant to provide protection against data mixing induced by faulty hardware) makes TCP blind spoofing much harder. However, this is fortuitous. In all fairness, we can state that **TCP/IP provides no real "security"** in the modern sense (where hackers brandish keyboards, not ICBM). Thus, listing TCP/IP weaknesses is "easy": it has all of them.

Stronger security features have nonetheless been applied later on, e.g. with [IPsec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec); or moved to another conceptual layer, as commonly occurs with [SSL/TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) or encrypted email protocols like S/MIME or PGP. In fact, TCP/IP is now most often used not as a provider of secure transport, but as a shared medium with shortcomings that are best addressed elsewhere in a different way.

Comment: I was under the impression that the nuclear war part of the Internet's history was just a myth? And instead it was just intended to be robust enough to prevent it from falling apart if different parts broke? re: http://www.internetsociety.org/internet/what-internet/history-internet/brief-history-internet

Comment: Though the ARPANET designers wanted a "scholarly" reliable network, they got substantial funding from the Military who were well aware of the potential of packet switching for resisting nuclear attacks -- thus helping to solve the biggest command&control problem of the US Strategic Air Command at that time. Claiming that ARPANET was unrelated to nuclear defence is like claiming that development of gunpowder had no relation whatsoever with war. That's self-inflicted mind blindness to ethically reconcile one's academic work with a more sinister context.

Comment: Thanks for the information, @ThomasPornin. So is it safe/correct to say it wasn't *directly* one of the reasons for ARPANET but it was, in a distinct way, part of the reason?

Comment: Even if it is not nuclear attacks specifically, making air strikes or other attacks against communication channels has always been a military tactic.